# How to loop over the entire python script and and each time change order ran

Tags: python, linux, loops, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to create a script to run in the background of a Linux system. I want it to check if certain conditions have been met; once they have, skip that section of code and not check anymore.

```
Loop = True
while True:
  V1 = None
  while True:
    print("Checked for vulnerability")
    if my_file.is_file():
        print('Virus is still there')
        time.sleep(6)
        os.system("rm /home/levi/Desktop/Trojan")
    else:
        print('Virus removed')
        V1 = False
        break

  print('Did this work')
```

I need to check V1: if `True`, then execute the loop.  When it loops around, set the value to `False` and end the script -- but it gets stuck in the else statement and never ends. I never see "did this work."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code fails with several syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tied yourself into a knot with a double-infinite loop.  You set two variables (Loop and V1, both poor names), and never use either to control the loop.  Try this: simply `break` the loop when you're done.

```
while True:
    print("Checked for vulnerability")
    if my_file.is_file():
        print('Virus is still there')
        time.sleep(6)
        os.system("rm /home/levi/Desktop/Trojan")
    else:
        print('Virus removed')
        break

print('Did this work')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two infinite loops, which can only be ended by a `break` statement. You do have a `break` statement in your code, but only one. A `break` statement will only break out of the most inner loop that it is in, in this case, your inner `while` loop. The outer `while` loop therefore will never end.
Although there are better ways of writing your code (like Prune has pointed out), I will give a suggestion that follows closely to your original code:

```
V1 = True
while V1 is True:
    print("Checked for vulnerability")
    if my_file.is_file():
        print('Virus is still there')
        time.sleep(6)
        os.system("rm /home/levi/Desktop/Trojan")
    else:
        print('Virus removed')
        V1 = False

print('Did this work')
```

I still removed the outer `while`-loop, since it serves no purpose in any way.
Unless, of course, you were going to add more to the outer loop than just an other loop, then you should re-add it. In that case however, you should define your code in the following way:

```
loop = True
V1 = True
while loop is True:
    while V1 is True:
        print("Checked for vulnerability")
        if my_file.is_file():
            print('Virus is still there')
            time.sleep(6)
            os.system("rm /home/levi/Desktop/Trojan")
        else:
            print('Virus removed')
            V1 = False
    # do something else here after ending the inner while loop

print('Did this work')
```

This ensures that the inner `while` loop is only ever executed once, no matter how many times the outer loop iterates.